# Variadic version of std::is_convertible?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates

Is it possible to write a variadic version of `std::is_convertible`? For example `are_convertible<T1, T2, T3, T4>` would return `is_convertible<T1, T3> && is_convertible<T2, T4>`. I've been thinking about this for a few hours but couldn't come up with anything reasonable.

To clarify I want to use it somewhat like this:

```
template <class ...Args1>
struct thing
{
  template <class ...Args2>
  enable_if_t<are_convertible<Args2..., Args1...>::value>
  foo(Args2 &&...args){}
}
```

Comment: What if there are 6 templates `(T1, T2, T3, T4, T5, T6)`? Seems like it might be better to group neighbors: `is_convertible<T1, T2> && is_convertible<T3, T4> && is_convertible<T5, T6>`.

Comment: @erip Then I would somehow need to interleave the arguments from two parameter packs, which seems just as difficult.

Comment: Why do they need to be interleaved?

Comment: @erip I updated my post with an example.

Comment: @user697683 You *really* don't want `thing<A, B>(c, d, e, f)` to compile just because `(D, E, F)` would be convertible `(A, B, C)`. You can't assume that your `Args1...` and `Args2...` are of the same length since nowhere do you have any assertion that they are of the same length.

Comment: @user697683 this is just a stupid example. real version would check if they're the same length.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't need to concatenate `Args2...` and `Args1...`, and you shouldn't, since doing to makes it makes it impossible to tell where `Args2...` ends and `Args1...` begins. The way to pass multiple variadic arguments in a way that allows them to be extracted individually is wrapping them in yet another template: given a variadic template `my_list`, you could structure your `my_convertible` to be called as

```
my_convertible<my_list<Args2...>, my_list<Args1...>>
```

The standard library already has a variadic template that works well here: `tuple`. Not only that, but `tuple<Args2...>` is convertible to `tuple<Args1...>` if and only if `Args2...` are convertible to `Args1...`, so you can just write:

```
std::is_convertible<std::tuple<Args2...>, std::tuple<Args1...>>
```

---

Note: in the comments, @zatm8 reports that this doesn't always work: `std::is_convertible<std::tuple<const char *&&>, std::tuple<std::string &&>>::value` is reported as `false`, but `std::is_convertible<const char *&&, std::string &&>::value` is reported as `true`.

I believe that this is a bug, that they should both be reported as `true`. The problem is reproducible on http://gcc.godbolt.org/ with clang 3.9.1. It is not reproducible with gcc 6.3, and it is also not reproducible with clang 3.9.1 when using `-stdlib=libc++`. It appears that libstdc++ is using a language feature that clang doesn't quite handle correctly, and reducing it to a short example that does not rely on standard library headers gives:

```
struct S {
  S(const char *) { }
};
int main() {
  const char *s = "";
  static_cast<S &&>(s);
}
```

This is accepted by gcc, but rejected by clang. It has been reported in 2014 as https://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=19917.

It appears that this has been fixed in late 2016, but the fix has not yet made it into a released version: http://lists.llvm.org/pipermail/cfe-commits/Week-of-Mon-20161031/175955.html

If you are affected by this, you may wish to avoid `std::tuple` and use @Yakk's answer instead.

Comment: Not for all types tuple is valid solution. Example: std::is_convertible_v<std::tuple<const char*&&>,std::tuple<std::string&&>> returns false, but std::is_convertible_v<const char*&&,std::string&&> returns true

Comment: @zatm8 Thanks for the comment. I believe this is a compiler bug, please see my edit.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

First, how to do it.  Then, why you shouldn't do it.

## How to do it:

Write regroup, that takes a list of kN elements and groups it into N groups of k, interleaved.  Groups can be `template<class...>struct types{};`.

Then write apply, that takes a `template<class...>class Z` and a `class...` of groups (aka `types<...>`), and applies `Z` to the contents of each of the bundles, returning a `types<...>` of the result.

Then fold over the contents of `types<...>` using `template<class A, class B> struct and_types:std::integral_constant<bool, A{}&&B{}>{};`.

I would find this mostly pointless, so I won't implement it.  It should be easy with a decent metaprogramming library, most of the above operations are bog-standard.

---

## Why you shouldn't

But really, given your example, just do this:

```
template<class...Ts>
struct and_types:std::true_type{};
template<class T0, class...Ts>
struct and_types<T0,Ts...>:std::integral_constant<bool, T0{} && and_types<Ts...>{}>{};
```

Then:

```
std::enable_if_t<and_types<std::is_convertible<Args2, Args1>...>{}>
```

does the job.  All of the shuffling is just noise.

With fold `...` support from C++1z, we get rid of `and_types` as well and just use `&&` and `...`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how to write the regroup or link to an implementation example? It could satisfy my curiosity :)

Comment: You could possibly also just check if the corresponding `tuple`s are assignable, but I'm not sure that solution comes out any simpler then your proposed one.

Comment: @ysc I can think of many ugly ways.  For a pretty way, ask someone who programs in lisp (or haskell), then translate to C++ TMP should work.  I mean, get_every_nth and pop_front_then and bind is one, or group into k groups of N (not interleaved), then rotate, is another.  All messy; hence find language with beautiful list primitives, and implement those.

Comment: I get it. It's quite simple finally. `template<size_t N, T...> struct at;` is the "hard" part, and it's feasible in a few lines.

Comment: @YSC the "few lines" version of `at` has O(N) instantiation depth. A high quality `at` does it in O(lg(N)) depth (still O(N) instances, but recursive depth is limited by using a tree structure), but requires more than few lines. This is important because the low-quality `at` generates O(N^2) in total typename length (so high memory/compile time costs), and compilers are typically limited in template instantiation recursion depth. (Write high-quality "split" first.  `split<X,list...>::left = concat< split<X/2, list... >::left, split<X-X/2, split<X/2, list...>::right>::left >` in pseudo-code.)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [std::conjuction](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conjunction) to fold all result types in one:

```
template <class... Args>
struct is_convertible_multi {
   constexpr static bool value = false;
};

template <class... Args1, class... Args2>
struct is_convertible_multi<::std::tuple<Args1...>, ::std::tuple<Args2...>> {
   constexpr static bool value =  ::std::conjunction_v<::std::is_convertible<Args1,Args2>...>;
};
```

And remember to check if

```
sizeof... (Args1) == sizeof... (Args2)
```

using if constexpr or enable_if