# How to unpack empty variadic template list

Tags: c++, c++11, metaprogramming, c++14, variadic-templates

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34615570/variadic-version-of-stdis-convertible) question and thought it was interesting, so I started playing with some code to see if I could get it to work, but I ran into an issue.

My approach is to use the head-tail idiom familiar to functional programming. However, I could not find a way to deal with an empty variadic template list, which would be the base case.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C {};
class D : public C {};

/*

// Forward declaration
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible;

*/

// There are no Args
template <>
struct are_convertible<> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// Check if the first two elements are convertible then recurse on the rest
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible {
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value && are_convertible<Args...>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "Are convertible A->B and C->D: " << are_convertible<A, B, C, D>::value << std::endl; // Should be false
}
```

I'm currently getting an error that states `'are_convertible' is not a class template`, so I tried to forward declare it, which gave this error:

> error: wrong number of template arguments (0, should be at least 2)

How can I fix my approach?

Comment: How you tried to forward-declare it?

Comment: @Petr Edited the question.

Comment: Haven't you tired to keep only the variadic parameter in forward declaration (i.e. drop `T1` and `T2`)?

Comment: Sure. `error: redeclared with 3 template parameters`.

Comment: Well, your specialization is wrong. T1 and T2 disappeared.

Comment: Unlike the question you linked, your code appears to assume that the caller wishes to test `is_convertible` for each subsequent pair of types. Was this intentional?

Comment: @AndyG Yes, it was intentional. This is so there's a well-defined ordering. See my commented question in the provided link for an explanation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have two problems.

First, with your forward declaration, you say that your template *always* accepts at least two arguments (`T1` and `T2`). If you want to allow no parameters for your struct, you need to forward-declare it with only variadic parameter:

```
template<typename... Args>
struct are_convertible;
```

Second, your second definition is not partial specialization, but a full general (anew) template definition that contradicts the previous forward declaration. What you need is partial specialization:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible<T1, T2, Args...> {
                    //^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

After this, your code works:

```
class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C {};
class D : public C {};

template<typename... Args>
struct are_convertible;

// There are no Args
template <>
struct are_convertible<> {
    static const bool value = true;
};

// Check if the first two elements are convertible then recurse on the rest
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible<T1, T2, Args...> {
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value && are_convertible<Args...>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "Are convertible A->B and C->D: " << are_convertible<A, B, C, D>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Are convertible B->A and D->C: " << are_convertible<B, A, D, C>::value << std::endl;
}
```

This prints `false` and `true`, which seems to be a correct result for me.

Comment: Both solutions that were provided were good, but this one in particular addressed the empty variadic (i.e., `<>`).

Answer (score 1):

Your specialization is wrong. `T1` and `T2` disappeared. Partially specialize for `T1` and `T2`, which implies no other parameters are left for `Args...`. Code below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

class A {};
class B : public A {};
class C {};
class D : public C {};


// Forward declaration
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible;

// There are no Args
template <typename T1, typename T2>
struct are_convertible<T1, T2> {
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value;
};

// Check if the first two elements are convertible then recurse on the rest
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Args>
struct are_convertible {
    static const bool value = std::is_convertible<T1, T2>::value && are_convertible<Args...>::value;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << std::boolalpha;
    std::cout << "Are convertible A->B and C->D: " << are_convertible<A, B, C, D>::value << std::endl; // Should be false
}
```

[<kbd>Live on Coliru</kbd>](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4c1ef5e7325a8a66)